# Customize selenium logs for failed tests

Tags: selenium, logging, protractor

As a result of my selenium tests used with protractor I have result list as follows:

```
[14:49:14] I/testLogger -

[14:49:14] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-0 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-1 failed 4 test(s)
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-2 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-3 failed 1 test(s)
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-4 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-5 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-6 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-7 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-8 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-9 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-10 failed 7 test(s)
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-11 failed 5 test(s)
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-12 failed 5 test(s)
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-13 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - chrome #01-14 passed
[14:49:14] I/launcher - overall: 22 failed spec(s)
[14:49:14] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Is it possible to customise this list with some more detailed info like for example for each failed test add a spec name ? Right now I have to scroll A LOT my console to match a browser instance with a spec taht failed.

Comment: What test framework are you using? i.e. Jasmine, Mocha etc.

Comment: I'm using Jasmine. Probably the answer of Gunderson will solve my problem. I will keep you informent after testing  Jasmin Spec Reporter

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Jasmine, there are some reporter options available to you.  Take a look at [Jasmine Spec Reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter), it's very easy to setup.  After you install via npm, simply require it in your config file and add a simple function to your `onPrepare()`, i.e.:

```
// conf.js
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
exports.config = {
  onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
          displayStacktrace: 'true',
          displaySpecDuration: 'true'
      }));
   };
};
```

If that is not exactly what you are looking for, there are a few other Reporters that people have made, or you can always create a [custom jasmine reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have a large number of tests/validations and I dump all my results to a CSV and then open it in Excel. Once the data is in Excel, you have the full power of Excel to filter the data, add pivot tables, etc. to see your data however you want.

You would just need to define what columns you care about. For your example, you might start with something like Test Name, Browser, Result, ???. Once this is in Excel, you Insert > Table and then filter by Result = Failed. Now you can see all the tests that failed. You could also create a pivot table to show you the summary of the run.

I created a custom Excel VBA macro that imports the CSV, converts the data to a table, and automatically creates a couple pivot tables for me. I use this on practically a daily basis and I can't imagine doing it any other way.